# Best resources for learning Gradle build tool

Tags: build, gradle

What are the best resources available to learn Gradle build tool from basic level?

Comment: For some reason, I like these questions where the user gets away with asking a "this-is-not-a-good-stackoverflow" question. He gets great answers, gathers a few upvotes, and only then is the question shut down. I dunno why, but I like it when this happens, especially when the question and its answers are useful to me.

Answer (score 29):

[Gradle user guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) is by far the best resource. You can start off by looking at the "Getting Started" chapter, it has a lot of good pointers to get you started with basic setup and build script basics.

Comment: Thanks for reply rodion. I would surely have a look at that but before I do that I wonder if there are some good video tutorials on Gradle to get up and running quickly.

Comment: sorry, nothing that I know of.

Answer (score 7):

Building and Testing with Gradle (from http://gradle.org/books/) is also worth a read for a high level overview of some options of what you can/may want to do.  Not nearly as comprehensive as the user guide but a good introduction.

Answer (score 3):

For video tutorials I would recommend the gradlewares webinars.
http://gradleware.com/resources

If you wan't more you can look at vimeo, there are many gradle videos there although with shifting quality.
Of the videos on vimeo I would recommend the ones with Luke Daley and Hans Dockter who both works at gradleware.

Comment: Yep, I went through `A GENTLE INTRODUCTION TO GRADLE` webinar and found that useful. Will have a go at videos at vimeo as well. Thanks:)